# Drawing a graph and grouping certain vertices together

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Let $G$ be a graph and let $\pi$ be a partition of the vertex set of $G$.

How would I tell mathematica to draw $G$ while keeping vertices in the same class of $\pi$ nearby? The application I have in mind is where $\pi$ is the partition given by the set of strongly connected components of the directed graph $G$.

Is there a built in command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`CommunityGraphPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CommunityGraphPlot.html).